# Sql Query To count "different way of stored data"

Tags: mysql, count, group-concat

Here is my Tables data

**Tickets**

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ id | tic_files                                                      |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 1  | 56456sasd.jpg,asd4455asd.jpg,asd564asd5.txt,asd564asd.css      |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 2  | 56a4sdasd.txt,jkasd5ass.jpg                                    |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 3  |                                                                |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 4  | asdjhagsd.gif,spsnd65asd.php,56a4sd54asd.txt                   |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

**Comments**

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ id | tic_id |  com_files                                                     |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 1  | 1      |  56456sasd.jpg,asd4455asd.jpg,asd564asd5.txt                   |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 2  | 3      |  56a4sdasd.txt,jkasd5ass.jpg                                   |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 3  | 1      |  sdf54sdf.gif,swrsdf54sdf.rar                                  |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 4  | 2      |  asdjhagsd.gif,spsnd65asd.php,56a4sd54asd.txt                  |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Here Is My Problem  And My retries

I want Result To Be Like This

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  tic_id |  count(tic_files)        | count(com_files)        |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  1      |         4                |      5                  |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  2      |         2                |      3                  |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  3      |         0                |      2                  |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  4      |         3                |      0                  |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

**i Tried To Do This**

Join  tickets with  group_concat( comments ) and fetch data some thing like this

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| tic_id | tic_files                                                 |  com_files                                                                |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| 1      | 56456sasd.jpg,asd4455asd.jpg,asd564asd5.txt,asd564asd.css | 56456sasd.jpg,asd4455asd.jpg,asd564asd5.txt,sdf54sdf.gif,swrsdf54sdf.rar  |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| 2      | 56a4sdasd.txt,jkasd5ass.jpg                               | asdjhagsd.gif,spsnd65asd.php,56a4sd54asd.txt                              |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| 3      |                                                           | 56a4sdasd.txt,jkasd5ass.jpg                                               |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| 4      | asdjhagsd.gif,spsnd65asd.php,56a4sd54asd.txt              |                                                                           |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

But i will try to use more than group_concat ( in all servers limit is 1024 kb  ) so i want to get count use delimiter between files " , "

***Solved***

This is my query

```
SELECT
                  cat_id as cat__id ,
                  cat_name,(
                    SELECT count(tickets.tic_id) from tickets INNER JOIN cats on(tickets.tic_cat = cats.cat_id) where tickets.tic_cat = cat__id  group by tickets.tic_cat limit 1
                  ) as "count(tickets)",(
                     SELECT  ( LENGTH( GROUP_CONCAT(tickets.tic_files)) - LENGTH( REPLACE( GROUP_CONCAT(tickets.tic_files ) , "," , "" ) ) + 1 )  FROM tickets
                     INNER join cats on ( tickets.tic_cat = cats.cat_id )
                     WHERE tickets.tic_files != "" AND  tickets.tic_cat = cat__id
                      LIMIT 1
                   )  as "count(ticket_files)",(
                    SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(tickets.tic_files)  FROM tickets
                     inner join cats on ( tickets.tic_cat = cats.cat_id )
                     WHERE tickets.tic_files != "" AND tickets.tic_cat = cat__id
                      LIMIT 1
                   ) as "tickets_files",
                  COUNT(comments.tic_id),(
                     SELECT  ( LENGTH( GROUP_CONCAT(comments.com_files)) - LENGTH( REPLACE( GROUP_CONCAT(comments.com_files ) , "," , "" ) ) + 1 )  FROM comments
                     INNER join tickets on ( tickets.tic_id = comments.tic_id )
                     INNER join cats on ( tickets.tic_cat = cats.cat_id )
                     WHERE comments.com_files != "" AND comments.tic_id = tickets.tic_id and tickets.tic_cat = cat__id
                      LIMIT 1
                   )  as "count(com_files)",(
                    SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(comments.com_files)  FROM comments
                     INNER join tickets on ( tickets.tic_id = comments.tic_id )
                     inner join cats on ( tickets.tic_cat = cats.cat_id )
                     WHERE comments.com_files != "" AND comments.tic_id = tickets.tic_id and tickets.tic_cat = cat__id
                      LIMIT 1
                   ) as "com_files"
            from tickets
            INNER JOIN cats ON (tickets.tic_cat = cats.cat_id)
            INNER JOIN comments ON ( comments.tic_id = tickets.tic_id )
  group by tickets.tic_cat
```

and here is picture of result

[image: Result Of My query]

Comment: I think your result table is a little bit wrong, it should be 2 for count(com_files) for a tic_id of 3, and 0 for count(com_files) for a tic_id of 4

Comment: This design is kind of crazy. Is it too late to fix it?

Comment: @Andrew Jackman , I Edit the question ,thank you

Comment: @ Álvaro G. Vicario yes its bad idea but help me many times :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to count the number of occurences in a string like this:

```
SELECT LENGTH( GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tic_files SEPARATOR ",") ) - LENGTH( REPLACE( GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tic_files SEPARATOR ",") , ',' , '' ) ) + 1 AS `TIC File Count`
```

This works by taking the total length of the column, then subtracting the length of the column after replacing all the characters you want to search for with an empty spaces.

So `56a4sdasd.txt,jkasd5ass.jpg` will become `56a4sdasd.txtjkasd5ass.jpg`, and the returned value will be 1.  You just need to add 1 and you will have the total number of strings around the delimiters.

Comment: Yes Your idea is very good  *i think you mean if my file length is 10 i will remove `,` and the result will be ( full length / 10 )*  right ,  but my file length is not same :(

Comment: There is no division going on.  This will look at the length of the string of file names. The length of `56a4sdasd.txt,jkasd5ass.jpg` is 28.  Then it removes all the ','s and finds a new length.  The length of `56a4sdasd.txtjkasd5ass.jpg` is 27.  Then it subtracts 28 - 27 which is 1.  Then it adds 1, which becomes 2.  And 2 is the count of file names in the string.

Comment: I just wonder if you can have a file called `One, two, three.jpg` :)

Comment: @Alvaro admittedly that will cause a miscount, but that being said, you shouldn't use a delimiter that is also a character that can exist in the data.

Comment: @AndrewJackman - I must clarify that I didn't intend to criticise your answer.

Comment: @AndrewJackman, +1 for such an interesting solution, but this will gives her the sum of all files in the column + 1 for the null one, I think you should add `group  by id`??

Comment: Yes  @Andrew Jackman  i think i now understand you   you mean get length of files with delimiter ","   then get length with files with out delimiter then the count is ( length with delimiter - length without delimiter  + 1 ) Great Idea Man :)

Comment: No problem @Alvaro I didn't feel criticised, and what you said is a very valid point (and something Mona should think about, when they validate filenames)

Comment: Thank You    @Andrew Jackman , Álvaro G. Vicario , MGA and me  Too :)   for helping me

Comment: i just add the result of my query :)